# Google Authenticator - What to keep for emergency restore

Tags: ssh, security, google-authenticator

I started to use Google Authenticator to secure my SSH servers with 2FA.

Running `$ google-authenticator` generates and prints a set of emergency keys beside a secret key and a verification code.

```
Your new secret key is: BLAHBLAHBLAH
Your verification code is 123456
Your emergency scratch codes are:
  00000000
  11111111
  22222222
  33333333
  44444444
```

I'm curious to know what are these codes and numbers? What should I backup to be on the safe zone in case of an emergency recovery?

Comment: `I'm curios to know what are these codes and numbers?` Those are the codes to use for recovery if your authenticator is lost.

Comment: If you have access to enabling/disabling the OTP from other means (eg, a second account that has a second authenticator) these recovery codes are less important, as you can use the second account to reset the first. But if the second account uses the same authenticator app, then you use these codes as backup.

Comment: Google Authenticator supports synchronization to your Google Account. Keeping the secret code allows you to avoid having to permit that action.  Likewise, the scratch codes, are just what they sound like one-time use codes in the event you don't have access to the authenticator (i.e. allowing you to disable 2FA Authentication and reenable it with a need Google Authenticator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow for access if you lose your OTP device, you backup all the 8 digit codes in a secure location. In such a scenario, your first task is to login (using a scratch code) and register a new OTP device - i.e. regenerate all the codes in this file.

If you are using Google as the authenticator provider (e.g. logging into gmail) and you can't log in with a OTP, they provide a separate interface to enter your scratch code (NB each code can only be used once).

The pam library is a bit simpler. If you [enter a 6 digit code](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam/blob/master/src/pam_google_authenticator.c#L1975) it will attempt to validate this as a TOTP/HOTP. If you enter an 8 digit code, it will validate it as a scratch code - i.e. a single use, non-expiring password.

The secret key is used as a salt for generating the OTP.

I don't know how the verification code is used.

Comment: Are you sure? I decrypted the QRCode which was the secret key included in it. So it's likely enough to recover an account.

Comment: Eh? QRcode is not encrypted. It is an encoded representation of the secret key. Both the authenticator device and the target use this to generate a OTP, and access is granted if they match. Yes, I'm sure. And yes, you can recover access if you retain the QR code - but you're not supposd to do that.

Comment: Oh my bad. I meant to say I've decode the qr code. So if the secret key is all what needed to generate an otp, why I need to keep a backup of those scratch codes?

Comment: Because keeping the scratch codes (limited usage) is less dangerous than keeping secret key (unlimited usage). But that only applies to to TOTP. For HOTP the secret key is no good wiithout the usage counter.

Answer (score 0):

You should store these codes in safe place. You can use them in case you do not have access to Authenticator.

Also will be wise to install on mobile device Google authenticator with the same account you use to register above software. This will replicate the OTP codes on you mobile device too.